# Инициализация полей Generic классов в конструкторе

Tags: java

К примеру есть такой класс

```
public class Dynemiclist<T> {
    private T[] data;
    private int count = 0;

    public Dynemiclist() {
        this(10);
    }

    private Dynemiclist(int size) {
        data = new T[size]

        count = 0;
    }
}
```

такую инициализацию      `data = new T[size]` подчеркивает компилятор, 
прочитал в статье что можно сделать так  `data = (T[]) new Object[size];` 
Почему не работает первый вариант и нужно делать как во втором?

Comment: Вы главу про type erasure в учебнике по Java пропустили?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вкратце, потому что Java так устроенна.

*Generic* в Java реализованы при помощи технологии [Type Erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure), она значит, что во время выполнения нет никаких *Generic*, *JVM* ничего про них не знает в принципе, они существуют только на стадии написания кода и во время компиляции заменяются на касты к тем классам, которые вы указываете. А в самим классах и методах, где вы написали `Generic` будет заменён на нижнюю границу возможного класса, например при `<T extends Number>` будет заменен на `Number`, если же просто `<T>` то на `Object`. В случае же если указано два ограничения, например `<T extends Iterable&Cloneable>`, то к первому из них, в данном случае к `Iterable`.

Массивы же не поддерживают [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure), потому что во время выполнение JVM необходимо знать тип создаваемого массива, а компилятор не может сам присвоить какой-либо тип на стадии компиляции. А происходит это потому, что Array это объект и у него есть поле class, и массивы разных классов имеют разное значение в поле класс. Если выполнить такой код:

```
System.out.println(new String[]{}.getClass());
System.out.println(new Object[]{}.getClass());
```

То результат будет такой:

```
class [Ljava.lang.String;
class [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Поэтому же если вы будете использовать `(T[]) new Object[size];` вы получите `ClassCastException`. И в этом же и есть принципиальная разница между всеми остальными случаями, например если выполнить такое:

```
System.out.println(new ArrayList<String>().getClass());
System.out.println(new ArrayList<Object>().getClass());
```

То получим:

```
class java.util.ArrayList
class java.util.ArrayList
```

Т.е. класс не поменялся и можно использовать Generic, потому что в это случае JVM не надо знать ничего про Generic.

Думаю вы уже прочитали, но посмотрите еще раз на главу про [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) в официальной документации.

Comment: `ClassCastException` там получится, только если у `T` задана граница, например `<T extends Number>`. Во время выполнения `T` будет стерт до `Number`, приводить `Object[]` к `Number[]` нельзя.

Comment: @zRrr даже если заданы, только не в момент каста в при любом обращении к этом массиву за пределами метода где он создался. Я про такое https://ideone.com/9Lfq5t

Comment: Да, если написать метод `<T> T[] getAll() {return (T[])new Object[5]}` и вызвать `Double[] d = getAll();` будет вылет, т.к. результат `getAll` будет приведен к `Double[]`. Если инициализировать поле `T[] array = (T[])new Object[5];`, то нет, т.к. `T` будет стерт до нижней границы везде внутри обобщенного класса.

Answer (score 1):

В далёком будущем (точно не в Java-9), когда допинают проект Valhalla, можно будет так делать. [Вот пример](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/valhalla/valhalla/jdk/file/2688b782367b/src/java.base/share/classes/java/anyutil/ArrayList.java#l150) `ArrayList`, переписанного на Valhalla:

```
public class ArrayList<any E> extends AbstractList<E>
        implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
    ...
    transient E[] elementData;

    ...

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private E[] getEmptyArray() {
        return new E[0];
    }

    private E[] copyOf(E[] input, int newSize) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        E[] array = new E[newSize];
        System.arraycopy(input, 0, array, 0, Math.min(input.length, newSize));
        return array;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Эх, далекое прекрасное будущее) Осталось до него дожить. Я так понимаю Generic будут более похожи на с++ template?

Comment: @Vartlok, ну не совсем, но для примитивных типов действительно будет в рантайме генерироваться отдельный класс.